# How to make a network usage analysis for an embed video

Tags: video, jwplayer

I own a small site and I plan to embed videos into my articles sometimes. I chose JW Player as my default video player, so these videos hosted externaly on JWPlayer's cloud will be inserted as an iframe into my site's code. I tried that and everything works fine.

However I know that a lot of people are using smartphones when browsing my site, so I would like to do something like a network analysis to ensure that it doesn't require a lot of bandwidth and that it will work fine. I am not an IT guy and need some guidence on what needs to be checked or done before launching videos on your site. Also I want to see how much it affects the network usage / loading time etc. Can I do some analysis using only Chrome Developer Tools? What else do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement @HeidiWF's answer - although it is not exactly what you asked, it may help.

You can also use analytics in the website to give you a measure of your site users experience.

For example, using Google Analytics (other analytics service are available also so this is just an example) and specially for video you can measure:

- metrics to measure what percentage of a video is watched
- metrics to measure when the buffer is empty
- average video bit rate

Google Analytics is directly supported in JWPlayer - more info here:

- https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1417179#fndtn-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

JW Player provides streams based on browser size and bandwidth availability (along with a couple of other considerations), so you should not have to worry about excessive data or bandwidth use with mobile. However, if you are curious and would like to peek into the network activity of a mobile device, both Chrome and Safari provide reliable dev tools for use with their respective devices (Android/iPhone). You will want to connect your phone to your computer, go to Dev Tools, and follow the steps here:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/
https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/